# Create an array off objects as a class member in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I keep getting errors when running the code below. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

> ERROR 1: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   line:25 char:9
>
> ERROR 2:  Cannot index into a null array. At line:43 char:1

CODE:

```
            Class Step {
                [int]$StepNumber = 0
                [string]$Name = ''
                [string]$ScriptFile = ''
                [int]$status = 0 # 0 = 'InComplete', 1 = 'Complete', 2 = 'Failed', -1 = 'Skipped'
                [string]$DependencyStepNumber = -1

                Step([string]$Name, [int]$StepNumber, [string]$ScriptFile) {
                    $this.Name = $Name
                    $this.StepNumber = $StepNumber
                    $this.ScriptFile = $ScriptFile
                }
            }


            Class Guide {
                [int]$StepNumberCounter = 0
                [string]$Name = ''
                [Step[]]$Steps

                [int]AddStep([string]$Name, [string]$ScriptFile) {
                    $newStepNumber = $this.GetNewStepNumber()
                    $newStep = [Step]::new($Name, $newStepNumber, $ScriptFile)

line-25>>>          $this.Steps.Add($newStep)

                    return $newStepNumber
                }

                [int]GetStepName([int]$StepNumber) {
                    return $this.Steps[$StepNumber-1]
                }

                [int]GetNewStepNumber() {
                    return $this.StepNumberCounter += 1
                }
             }

             $Guide = [Guide]::new()
             $Guide.AddStep('Step One','ScriptOne.ps1')
             $Guide.AddStep('Step Two','ScriptTwo.ps1')

line-43>>>   Write-Host $Guide.Steps[0]
             Write-Host $Guide.Steps[1]
```

Comment: Please indicate which is line 25 and 43.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array list has better performance, see below revised code

```
Class Step {
    [int]$StepNumber = 0
    [string]$Name = ''
    [string]$ScriptFile = ''
    [int]$status = 0 # 0 = 'InComplete', 1 = 'Complete', 2 = 'Failed', -1 = 'Skipped'
    [string]$DependencyStepNumber = -1

    Step([string]$Name, [int]$StepNumber, [string]$ScriptFile) {
        $this.Name = $Name
        $this.StepNumber = $StepNumber
        $this.ScriptFile = $ScriptFile
    }
}


Class Guide {
    [int]$StepNumberCounter = 0
    [string]$Name = ''
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$Steps = @()

    [int]AddStep([string]$Name, [string]$ScriptFile) {
        $newStepNumber = $this.GetNewStepNumber()
        $newStep = [Step]::new($Name, $newStepNumber, $ScriptFile)

        $this.Steps.Add($newStep)

        return $newStepNumber
    }

    [int]GetStepName([int]$StepNumber) {
        return $this.Steps[$StepNumber-1]
    }

    [int]GetNewStepNumber() {
        return $this.StepNumberCounter += 1
    }
}

$Guide = [Guide]::new()

$Guide.AddStep('Step One','ScriptOne.ps1')
$Guide.AddStep('Step Two','ScriptTwo.ps1')

Write-Output $Guide.Steps[0]
Write-Output $Guide.Steps[1]
```

Comment: Yes, this solves it with my original intent of using an ArrayList, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To add an element to an array, we use the += operator.

```
$this.Steps += $newStep
```

Add is reserved for ArrayList:

```
$al = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$al.Add('Example')
```

Comment: Jean-Claude Colette is correct, switch to using `+=` instead of `Add()`.

Comment: Thanks! That was it.